# how to turn on/off automatic date/time settings

Tags: settings, tasker, shell

I would like to be able to turn the automatic date time settings on and off from tasker.  I don't see a way to do this directly but I can use tasker to issue a shell command.  I know I can just use the date command to change the date to some specific date but is there a way to turn the automatic setting off and on from a command line or tasker?

Comment: If your problem is incorrect DST info - you can just update timezone database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be useful to check the android [source](https://android.googlesource.com/) to find the exact package name to the system [settings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/), specifically this [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/DateTimeSettings.java) responsible for date/time, line 226 is the key!

*Have played with tasker before, but can tasker directly modify system properties?* as in directly do this, I am quoting line 228 the pertinent part:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(
        getContentResolver(), 
        Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, 
        autoZoneEnabled ? 1 : 0);
```

In short the actual direct name to the package would be `com.android.settings/.DateTimeSettings`, if that's of any help!

By using `adb shell`'s Android Activity Manager, `am`, one can start the activity to go directly into that screen as in `am start -n com.android.settings/.DateTimeSettings`, experiment and see if that fits your needs as I have not actually played with it. :)

Comment: There is also a `Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME` settings that you can also disable for auto date & time.

Comment: The setting wasn't working for me on Android10/Q but this method worked:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68055904/573377


    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), DeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    dpm.setGlobalSetting(component, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, enable ? "1" : "0");

Answer (score 9):

turn on:

```
settings put global auto_time 1
```

turn off:

```
settings put global auto_time 0
```

source: Android sourcecode

Comment: An example using ADB would be: `$ adb shell settings put global auto_time 1`